# Show all dynamic changes on button press

Tags: dynamic, list-manipulation, button

This is probably a silly question, but I've spent all day trying to figure it out and I can't. Below is the code.

```
Button[
 Dynamic[
  x,
  Initialization :> {x = 0},
  TrackedSymbols :> {x}
  ],
 Table[
  Pause[0.1]; x++,
  {i, 1, 10}
  ]
 ]
```

When I press the button, the button label jumps from 0 to 10. What I want it to do is show all the values from 0 to 10 (i.e. dynamically update the label every time the value of x changes).

Gabriel

Comment: does `Button[Dynamic[x], x = 0; Table[Pause[0.1]; x++, {i, 1, 10}], 
 Method -> "Queued"]` give what you need?

Comment: yes >_<. thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the option `Method -> "Queued"`:

```
Button[Dynamic[x], 
  x = 0; Table[Pause[0.1]; x++, {i, 1, 10}], Method -> "Queued"]
```

[Button >> Details and options](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Button.html)

[image]